# In React how do I put an element onto the DOM before render() runs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using React (with Rails) and using a charting library called AnyChart. However the AnyChart code that I have in my render automatically looks for a `<div id="container"></div>` element to attach the chart onto. If I put the chart code in the render with the container div, then it gives an error because the chart code can't find the div because its not on the DOM yet.

I tried googling and only found stuff about portals and refs which didn't seem to apply to my problem.

I know I could move the container div to the layout view template but I want to be able to render other stuff on the component below the chart. Here is my entire StockContainer component and InputField component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import InputField from '../components/InputField'

class StockContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      stockTicker: ''
    }
    this.handleStockTickerChange = this.handleStockTickerChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClearForm = this.handleClearForm.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleClearForm(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      stockTicker: ''
    });
  }

  handleStockTickerChange(event) {
    this.setState({stockTicker: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let body = {
      symbol: this.state.stockTicker
    }
    console.log("Getting stock data for: " + body.symbol)
    this.handleClearForm(event);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  }

  render() {

    var table, mapping, chart;

    table = anychart.data.table();
    table.addData([
    ['2015-12-25', 512.53, 514.88, 505.69, 507.34],
    ['2015-12-26', 511.83, 514.98, 505.59, 506.23],
    ['2015-12-27', 511.22, 515.30, 505.49, 506.47],

     ...sample data that will later be imported from an API
 
    ['2016-01-07', 510.93, 516.07, 506.00, 510.99],
    ['2016-01-08', 510.88, 515.93, 505.22, 509.95],
    ['2016-01-09', 509.12, 515.97, 505.15, 510.12],
    ['2016-01-10', 508.53, 516.13, 505.66, 510.42]
    ]);

    // mapping the data
    mapping = table.mapAs();
    mapping.addField('open', 1, 'first');
    mapping.addField('high', 2, 'max');
    mapping.addField('low', 3, 'min');
    mapping.addField('close', 4, 'last');
    mapping.addField('value', 4, 'last');

    // defining the chart type
    chart = anychart.stock();

    // set the series type
    chart.plot(0).ohlc(mapping).name('ACME Corp.');

    // setting the chart title
    chart.title('AnyStock Demo');

    // display the chart
    chart.container('container');
    chart.draw();

    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Research/Add a Stock</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <InputField
            label='Stock Symbol'
            name='ticker'
            content={this.state.stockTicker}
            handleChange={this.handleStockTickerChange}
          />
          <input type='submit' value='Get Info'/>
        </form>
        <div id="container"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default StockContainer;

import React from 'react';

const InputField =(props) =>{
  return(
    <label>{props.label}
      <input
      type='text'
      name={props.name}
      value={props.content}
      onChange={props.handleChange}
      />
    </label>
  )
}
 export default InputField
```

Comment: Have you tried it inside componentDidMount()? The div should be rendered by then.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, the chart will be need to be regenerated using new data from an API every time the button is clicked, so putting the code in componentDidMount won't work because it only runs once.

Comment: I'm guessing the button that refreshes the data is in a different component? Or is it also in this component?

Comment: You could create a state to track if render has happened (eg: hasRenderedOnce: false). You could create chart once in componentDidMount and update the state (this.setState({ hasRenderedOnce: true }). In render, if hasRenderedOnce === true, create the chart again, if false, skip the chart creation.
Another way could be to check for new data and create chart in componentWillReceiveProps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work correctly. Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import InputField from '../components/InputField'

const divStyle = {
  // width: '100%',
  // height: '100%'
};

class StockContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      stockTicker: '',
      currentPrices: [],
      show: false
    }
    this.handleStockTickerChange = this.handleStockTickerChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClearForm = this.handleClearForm.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.getDataForStockChart = this.getDataForStockChart.bind(this);
  }

  handleClearForm(event){
    // event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ stockTicker: '' });
  }

  handleStockTickerChange(event) {
    this.setState({stockTicker: event.target.value});
  }

  getDataForStockChart(){
    let arrayOfArrays = []
    fetch(`https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/${this.state.stockTicker}/chart/1y`)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response;
      } else {
        let errorMessage = `${response.status} (${response.statusText})`,
          error = new Error(errorMessage);
        throw(error);
      }
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
      body.forEach(obj => {
        arrayOfArrays.push([obj["date"], obj["open"], obj["high"], obj["low"], obj["close"]]);
      });
      this.setState({
        show: true,
        currentPrices: arrayOfArrays
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(`Error in fetch: ${error.message}`));
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
    var table, mapping, chart;

    if (this.state.currentPrices.length > 1 && this.state.show){
      this.refs.myInput.innerHTML = '';
      // node = this.myRef.current
      table = anychart.data.table();
      table.addData(this.state.currentPrices);

      mapping = table.mapAs();
      mapping.addField('open', 1, 'first');
      mapping.addField('high', 2, 'max');
      mapping.addField('low', 3, 'min');
      mapping.addField('close', 4, 'last');
      mapping.addField('value', 4, 'last');

      chart = anychart.stock();

      chart.plot(0).ohlc(mapping).name('Stock Chart');
      chart.title('AnyStock Demo');
      chart.container('container');
      chart.draw();
      this.setState({show: false})
      this.handleClearForm(event);
    }
  }
  // shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
  //   if (this.state.show)
  // }

  handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    this.getDataForStockChart();
    this.handleClearForm();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Research/Add a Stock</h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <InputField
            label='Stock Symbol'
            name='ticker'
            content={this.state.stockTicker}
            handleChange={this.handleStockTickerChange}
          />
          <input type='submit' value='Get Info'/>
        </form>
        <div id="container" ref="myInput" style={divStyle}></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default StockContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Ishwor mentioned in the comment above, have you tried moving the `chart.container()` and `chart.draw()` methods into the component's `componentDidMount()` hook?

If you can provide the rest of the code for your component, we might be able to help.

```
import React from 'react';
import InputField from '../components/InputField'

class StockContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      stockTicker: ''
    }

    let table = anychart.data.table();
    table.addData([
    ['2015-12-25', 512.53, 514.88, 505.69, 507.34],
    ['2015-12-26', 511.83, 514.98, 505.59, 506.23],
    ['2015-12-27', 511.22, 515.30, 505.49, 506.47],

    ...sample data that will later be imported from an API
    ]);

    // mapping the data
    let mapping = table.mapAs();
    mapping.addField('open', 1, 'first');
    mapping.addField('high', 2, 'max');
    mapping.addField('low', 3, 'min');
    mapping.addField('close', 4, 'last');
    mapping.addField('value', 4, 'last');

    // defining the chart type
    let chart = anychart.stock();

    // set the series type
    chart.plot(0).ohlc(mapping).name('ACME Corp.');

    // setting the chart title
    chart.title('AnyStock Demo');

    // to be able to reference these later, if needed
    this.table = table;
    this.mapping = mapping;
    this.chart = chart;

    this.handleStockTickerChange = this.handleStockTickerChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClearForm = this.handleClearForm.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    // draw the chart
    this.drawMyAwesomeChart = this.drawMyAwesomeChart.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.chart.container('container');
    this.drawMyAwesomeChart()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    // do some checks here to see if you need to draw chart?
    // this.drawMyAwesomeChart()
  }

  drawMyAwesomeChart() {
    this.chart.draw();
  }

}
```

You could then bind a function that specifically is responsible for refreshing the chart whenever the stock ticker changes. I haven't fully tested this, but something along these lines should work?

Comment: I added the rest of the code to my post, but the data will be taken from an API, so it will need to regenerate the chart every time the page re-renders (when the button is clicked). So I don't think putting it in the componentDidMount will work cause that function only runs once on mount.

Comment: you can create a separate method which will handle the chart.draw logic and call that function in both component.DidMount and in componentDidUpdate lifecycle method. As componentDidMount will handle the initial render and componentDidUpdate will handle the future updates

Comment: using componentDidUpdate or componentWillReceiveProps, you can check to see whether you need to redraw the chart or not, and then proceed from there

Answer (score 0):

Try using life cycle methods componentDidUpdate